# Fails on Running Cassandra Server

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

This is the error information I get:

```
Full Product Version :
Fails on java version. It's Java "1.8.0_181"
Os Version : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
EXTRA RELEVANT SYSTEM CONFIGURATION :
Just installed Cassandra 2.2.11 
A DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM : 
#A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007f42fc492e70, pid=12128, tid=0x00007f42fc3c9700
#JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
SYSTEM CONFIGURATION :
1.CPU - Intel Core i7 - 4771 CPU @ 3.50 GHz * 8
2. RAM - 16 GB
3. STORAGE - 967.6 GB
4. OS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
5. Apache Cassandra - 2.2.11
6. CPP Driver - 2.2.1-1
7. libuv - 1.4.2-1 
8. Java version - "1.8.0_181" 
Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java Hotspot (TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Cassandra was working normally before generating this bug. Now when i am trying to restart my server getting this output.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: And for the record: "please help me asap" comes over plain rude.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it reminds me of [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14173) where java8 updates prevented cassandra from loading. You can try downgrading your java to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: This bug is not related to java8 update because it was working fine intially but after loading some data , this bug has been produced.

Comment: Anyone who can help me in this issue on  urgent basis ?